# Not able to display the content on the grid dynamically from database

Tags: json, extjs

I want to display load the form data from database and display that data into grid. But while doing that task I am facing one problem i.e., I am unable to get the JSON response into grid only empty rows are adding to the grid.

Here is my Grid code:

```
Ext.define('test.view.user.PredictabilityGrid' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.predictabilitygrid',
title: 'Predictability Grid',

store:'UserGrid',
height: 200,
width: 400,
columns: [
          {     header: 'SAP ID',
                dataIndex:'userId'
          },
          {
              header: 'Name',
              dataIndex: 'userName'
              //id: 'gridName'

          },
          {
              header: 'Status',
              dataIndex: 'status'
          },
          {
              header: 'EDC Name',
              dataIndex: 'edcName'
          },
          {
              header: 'BHR',
              dataIndex: 'businessHr'
          },
          {
              header: 'Level',
              dataIndex: 'level'
          },
          {
              header: 'Designation',
              dataIndex: 'designation'
          },
          {
              header: 'Resign Date',
              dataIndex: 'dor'
          },
          {
              header: 'DOJ',
              dataIndex: 'doj'
          },
          {
              header: 'Manager',
              dataIndex: 'directManager'
          },
          {
              header: 'Indirect Manager',
              dataIndex: 'indirectManager'
          },
          {
              header: 'Quarter',
              dataIndex: 'quarter'
          },
          {
              header: 'Year',
              dataIndex: 'year'
          },
          {
              header: 'Predictability',
              dataIndex: 'predict'
          },
          {
              header: 'Primary Reason',
              dataIndex: 'primary'
          },
          {
              header: 'Secondary Reason',
              dataIndex: 'secondary'
          },
          {
              header: 'Probable Attrition Category',
              dataIndex: 'attrition'
          },
          {
              header: 'Criticality',
              dataIndex: 'criticality'
          },
          {
              header: 'Action Planned By Manager(1)',
              dataIndex: 'action1'
          },
          {
              header: 'Action Planned By Manager(2)',
              dataIndex: 'action2'
          },
          {
              header: 'Details',
              dataIndex: 'details'
          },
          {
              header: 'Dependency',
              dataIndex: 'dependency'
          },
          {
              header: 'Remarks',
              dataIndex: 'remarks'
          }],
          dockedItems:[{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked:'top',
                height:50,
                items: [{
                    text:   'HrApps',
                    icon:   'hrapps.jpg'
                },{
                        xtype: 'tbfill'
                },{
                    itemId:'btnHomeGrid',
                    text: 'Home',
                    icon:'home.jpg'
                },{
                    itemId:'btnChangeGrid',
                    text:   'ChangePassword',
                    icon:'changepass.jpg'
                },{
                    itemId:'btnLogoutGrid',
                    text:'Logout',
                    icon:'Logout.jpg'
                }]
            }]
    });
```

Here is my grid store:

```
Ext.define('test.store.UserGrid', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
storeId:'UserGrid',
autoLoad: false,
alias : 'widget.UserGrid',
itemId:'UserGrid',
fields: ['userName','userId',
         'status',
         'edcName',
         'businessHr',
        'level',
         'doj',
         'designation',
         'directManager',
         'indirectManager',
         'quarter',
        'year',
         'dor',
         'predict',
       'primary',
         'secondary',
            'attrition',
            'criticality',
            'action1',
            'action2',
            'details',
            'dependency',
         'remarks'
         ]
   });
```

Here is my extjs controller code for displaying data into the grid:

In the following code I am storing the data into the form and getting that back and displaying it into the grid.

```
onSavePredict:function(button)
    {
        var predictabilityDetails = this.getPredictabilityForm().getForm().getValues();
        var form = button.up('predictability').getForm();
            Ext.Ajax.request({ 
                params : {
                predictData : Ext.encode(predictabilityDetails)
            },
                url: 'test/createPredictability', 
                success: function(response, options){
                var jsonResponse = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                panel = button.up('parentPage');
                panel.getLayout().setActiveItem(5);
                form.reset();
                Ext.Ajax.request({ 
                    params : {
                    grid_data : Ext.encode(predictabilityDetails)
                },
                url: 'test/createGrid',
                success: function(response, options,record){
                    var jsonResponse = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                    //this.getView().get(predictabilitygrid).getStore();
                    //alert(jsonResponse.predict.get().userName);
                    Ext.getStore('UserGrid').load();
                Ext.getStore('UserGrid').add(0,jsonResponse.predict);

                    /*userStore.insert(0, predictabilityDetails);   
                    predictabilityDetails.loadRecord(record);
                    predictabilityDetails.updateRecord();*/
                    }
                });
            }
            });
```

Here is my JSON response:

> {"predict":[{"predict":"Moderately Certain","primary":"aaa","secondary":"ccc","attrition":"Regretted"
>   ,"criticality":"Critical","action1":"permanent","action2":"good","actionstatus":"Pending","details":"as"
>   ,"dependency":"sa","remarks":"dsd","userName":"supriya","userId":"7164921","status":"Inactive","edcName"
>   :"HDC","businessHr":"suresh","level":"L1","doj":"03/05/2015","designation":"intern","directManager":"sridhar"
>   ,"indirectManager":"amith","year":"2015","quarter":"q1","dor":""}]}

How to make the data get  displayed on the grid dynamically from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should remove "alias : 'widget.UserGrid'" and "itemId:'UserGrid'" from your store. Makes no sense. Create a model to bind to your store and config a ajax proxy onto your store. Then you just call store.load().

Comment: Where to add store.load()

Comment: Though adding proxy and store.load() there is same result

Comment: And one more question how to export that grid data into excel file.